# AddType application/x-httpd-php .php is not rendering PHP

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, content-negotiation

Adding this code:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` after

```
# AddEncoding x-compress .Z
# AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
#
# If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
# probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
#
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

to
`C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.conf`
downloads all PHP pages on my system rather than render it.

Before then, the PHP pages were parsed as raw text.

Help needed!

Comment: Are you using PHP as fcgi or apache module

Comment: PHP as Apache module

Comment: Make sure that the code is between <?php ?> tag

Comment: @RajendranNadar It is between the `<?php ?>` tags... Do you think it is an installation problem?

Comment: Did you add the `LoadModule` line to `httpd.conf` yet, so that PHP is actually loaded into apache

Comment: Nope, not yet... That may be it then?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: Please share more details - `AddType` only sets a `Content-Type` header that is sent to the client. It does not configure how any type is handled on the server

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems:

1. `application/x-httpd-php` is not a MIME type, but rather a handler. That means your directive must be `AddHandler` instead of `AddType`
2. `application/x-httpd-php` is not a valid handler. The handler must include the PHP version digits at the end of the string

Putting that altogether, assuming, say PHP version 7.2, what you want is

✅ `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php` instead of 
    `AddType    application/x-httpd-php   .php`

Comment: This really ought to be the accepted answer... this fixed up some old pages right up for me after the hosting company auto-upgraded the site to PHP 7. Thanks, Lucas.

Comment: for me it worked like this: (without version)
```AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php```

Comment: wrt. 1) It doesn't matter at all, whether it is a mime type or not! Everything what matters is, whether the module accepts this string, when it gets asked to process the request. If it gets passed an unknown name, it simply ignores the request. Wrt. 2) This is wrong wrt. to default code. The unmodified, i.e. original code accepts `application/x-httpd-php`, `application/x-httpd-php-source`, and `php-script`, only (see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L60).

Answer (score -1):

```
add this at the bottom of your httpd.conf make sure you have php{version}apache{version}.dll in line 3 and directory of  your php.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php7"
```

you can visit this [link](https://armantutorial.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/how-to-install-wamp-apache-2-4-and-php-7-3/)