# Not able to access to my server with domain registered in route53 but can access via its ec2 ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've a domain(**http://yurr.app**) I add it in route53 hosted zone and point the a record to ec2 ip(http://3.84.101.4/). I checked dns checker and my domain pointing to the ip I added
I can access my ip and can see it but I can't visit it with my domain.
I'm not sure what I miss or why not able to access it

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are redirecting `http://yurr.app` to `https://yurr.app`, and your website is not set up to receive HTTPS traffic.

Comment: How can I fix this? I want to do it with aws certificate manager. Can you please guide me

Comment: @ziasultan To fix this, you have to install ssl certificate on your web server in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fixed it by adding those two lines inside ***/public/.htaccess*** file:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

[AddType application/x-httpd-php .php is not rendering PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773440/addtype-application-x-httpd-php-php-is-not-rendering-php)